# `Deploy` doesn't seem to work on cloud

Tags: graphics, cloud-deploy, deployment

In the notebook interface `Deploy` prevents the orange frame of a `Graphics` object from showing, but this doesn't work on the web. Specifically,

```
CloudDeploy[
 Manipulate[
  Deploy@Graphics[{
     If[c1, Red, Black],
     EventHandler[RegularPolygon[5], 
      "MouseClicked" :> (c1 = Not@c1)],
     If[c2, Red, Black],
     EventHandler[RegularPolygon[{0.5, -1.2}, {0.3, 0.2}, 5], 
      "MouseClicked" :> (c2 = Not@c2)]
     },
    ContentSelectable -> False
    ],
  {c1, {False, True}},
  {c2, {False, True}}
  ],
 "polyclick",
 Permissions -> "Public"
 ]
```

still shows the orange frame like this:

[image]

when you click on it. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Adding `Deployed -> True` to the `Manipulate` also doesn't help.

Comment: I would try to inspect css and add EmbeddedHTML with styles to overwrite it.